# Saving for a house, is holding money in the bank account currently wise?

Tags: mortgage, savings, poland

I was currently saving to buy a new house with as lowest mortgage as possible (have currently money in the normal bank account without any interest rates) and planning to make a buy around the middle of this year.

With the current coronavirus crisis I am a little worried of potential outcomes when the situation will settle. Should I consider going for credit now or invest in something to protect myself from economic crisis?

For context I am living in Poland.

Comment: Only invest in something you have knowledge in or in something that someone you trust a 100% has excellent knowledge in, especially in times of fluctuation and uncertainty. That being said, you should have lines of credit available for your disposal when needed and that's irrelevant of the current market (unless you are a spontaneous buyer).